# XML solr update and solr handlr java 500 error

Tags: java, solr

When I try to import my xml file (which is formatted as such):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<add>
<doc>
    <field name="last_updated">content</field>
        <field name="identifier">
            <field name="id">content</field>
            <field name="type">content</field>
        </field>
        <field name="identifier">
            <field name="id">content</field>
            <field name="type">content</field>
        </field>
        <field name="journal">
            <field name="volume">content</field>
            <field name="country">content</field>
            <field name="content">
                <field name="open_access">content</field>
                <field name="title">content</field>
                <field name="type">content</field>
                <field name="url">content</field>
            </field>
            <field name="issns">content</field>
            <field name="publisher">content/field>
            <field name="language">content</field>
            <field name="title">content</field>
        </field>
        <field name="month">content</field>
        <field name="keywords">content</field>
        <field name="keywords">content</field>
        <field name="keywords">content</field>
        <field name="keywords">content</field>
        <field name="keywords">content</field>
        <field name="year">content</field>
        <field name="subject">
            <field name="code">content</field>
            <field name="scheme">content</field>
            <field name="term">content</field>
        </field>
        <field name="term">
            <field name="affiliation">content</field>
            <field name="name">content</field>
        </field>
        <field name="link">
            <field name="content_type">HTML</field>
            <field name="type">fulltext</field>
            <field name="url">content/full</field>
        </field>
        <field name="abstract">content</field>
    
    <field name="admin">
        <field name="seal">true</field>
    </field>
    <field name="created_date">content</field>
    <field name="id">content</field>
</doc>

[continues]
</add>
```

I keep on receiving the following error when I try to post it to solr via the: `java -Dc=articles -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar DOAJ_1.xml` command.

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 (Server Error) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">500</int>
  <int name="QTime">39</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <str name="trace">java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:110)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:261)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:188)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2551)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:733)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:531)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:395)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:341)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
</str>
  <int name="code">500</int>
</lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/update...
Time spent: 0:00:28.239
```

I hope that I have provided enough information, if not, please let me know and I would be happy to provide more details. I would really appreciate it if anyone could try and help me figuring this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is thrown in a update processor - which version of Solr? If it's recent, this is probably the offending line: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java#L110

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using the latest version of Solr (8.6) and also tried 7.7 and 8.0, yet can not get it to work. Is there a similar way I can import (relatively large) json files? Since I also have the json datasets.